# How to use ssh tool to print a fingerprint without blocking

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I need to get the fingerprint of a machine in a local network, so there's no risk of me getting a man in the middle fingerprint. My best attempt to get the fingerprint was to try to ssh into the machine using the `ssh` command line tool. However, it has the inconvenient that is blocks, sayign that

```
The authenticity of host '...' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is...
```

with a prompt for `yes` or `no`.

I really need this to work without blocking, so is there a paremeter that I can pass to ssh that will print the fingerprint but don't block it nor connect to it? Maybe another native tool from ubuntu would do the work?